# How can I help SumConvergence give the right result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I've been trying to use the `SumConvergence` on the following series:

```
SumConvergence[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), n]
```

This returns False on Mathematica 11.3, but I suspect this is incorrect since:

$$\frac{1}{n \log(n) \log(n \log(n))} < \frac{1}{n \log(n) \log(n)} $$

attempting to check the convergence of the RHS

```
SumConvergence[1/(n Log[n] Log[n]), n]
```

returns `True`.  So by direct comparison, the initial series should converge. I've also plotted the two functions to further justify the argument.

[image: A comparison between the two series.]

What can I do to help `SumConvergence` recognize that the initial series converges?

Comment: *Mathematica* seems to like the comparison tests less than calc. students: `Reduce[n > 1 && 1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]) < 1/(n Log[n] Log[Log[n]]), n, Integers]` and `Limit[(n Log[n]^y)/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 1 < y < 1 + 1/10^6]` show convergence, but I don't know how to teach `SumConvergence` the comparison methods.

Comment: Still a bug in 13.3. Crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is `` Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm[] ``, which mistakenly decides the sum is not convergent.  It should be reported as a bug.  (It would be acceptable if it couldn't decide, but to reach the wrong conclusion is wrong.)

Here's a modest implementation of the limit comparison test within the log-testing code. It uses the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) to insert the code ahead of the built-in `UnivariateLogarithm[]` codes.  We need to manually insert it as the first code in the `DownValues`, so that it is called before other definitions of `UnivariateLogarithm[]`.  Since `UnivariateLogarithm[]` is buggy, it's a question whether I should call it (or `SumConvergence[]`, which in turn would call it) after the comparison test to check convergence of the transformed series.  I probably shouldn't unless I can prove I've avoided the bug, but just how much work should I do rooting around undocumented functions for free?  Better to let WRI decide how to fix their software.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm},

 DownValues[Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm] = Prepend[
   DownValues[Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm],
   (* new def. for UnivariateLogarithm[] *)
   HoldPattern[
     Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm[expr_, k_] /;
       ! TrueQ[$inLimitComparisionTestQ] && ! FreeQ[expr, _Log]
     ] :> Block[{$inLimitComparisionTestQ = True},
     Module[{factors, comparisons, log, nlogs, res},
      factors = Rest@FactorList[expr];
      nlogs = Max[Count[#, _Log, Infinity, Heads -> True] & /@ 
         factors[[All, 1]]];
      factors = Power @@@ factors;
      log = k; (* log is the iterated composition of Log[] 
                  with k up to nlogs number of times *)
      While[Depth[log] <= nlogs + 1 && ! TrueQ@res,
       comparisons = Abs@Limit[log*factors, n -> Infinity];
       res = Sum`SumConvergenceDump`UnivariateLogarithm[
         Times @@ ReplacePart[
           factors,
           Position[comparisons, L_ /; 0 < L < Infinity] -> 1/log],
         k];
       log = Log@log
       ];
      res /; TrueQ@res
      ]
     ]
   ];

 SumConvergence[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), n]
 ]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: It would be useful if Method->"IntegralTest" uses the numeric integration in some cases.

Comment: @user64494 One can use `NSum[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), {n, 2, Infinity}]`, if one wants an approximate verification of convergence via `NIntegrate`.  One can try to substitute `NIntegrate` for `Integrate` for `SumConvergence`, but I think it will almost always return `True` since `NIntegrate` almost always returns a numeric result: `Block[{Integrate = NIntegrate}, SumConvergence[1/n, n, Method -> "IntegralTest"]]`.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you for your comprehensive analysis of my suggestion. There is a room to improve NIntegrate for divergent improper integrals.

Comment: Compare NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 1, Infinity}] which results 191612. with the command of Maple int(1/x, x = 1 .. infinity, numeric) which performs Float(infinity).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in  two steps.

1. `ForAll[n, n >= 2, D[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), n] <= 0];Resolve[%, Reals]
   *True*`
2. `NIntegrate[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), {n, 2, Infinity}] 
   *1.42474*`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example where you already need Bertrand test. Indeed, the series is positive, and thus the "Raabe failure means try Bertrand" applies.

Indeed, try Raabe:

```
b[n_] = 1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]); 

Limit[n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1), n -> Infinity]
```

it prints 1, that means nothing, you need to increase the complexity of the test (Bertrand):

```
Limit[Log[n] (n (b[n]/b[n + 1] - 1) - 1), n -> Infinity]
```

prints 2, that means converges.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [Ermakoff's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697460/example-where-ermakoffs-convergence-test-is-inconclusive), which in general is much more powerful than the ratio test. I've only seen one example where a (nonincreasing) summand is inconclusive (the answer in the linked question).

```
eventuallyNonIncreasing[expr_, n_] := FunctionMonotonicity[{expr, n > 10000}, n, Reals] === -1

sumConvergenceErmakoff[expr_, n_] /; eventuallyNonIncreasing[expr, n] :=
    Block[{limmand, lim},
        limmand = Exp[n]*(expr /. n -> Exp[n])/expr;
        lim = Quiet[Limit[limmand, n -> ∞]];
        (
            lim < 1
        ) /; NumericQ[lim] && !PossibleZeroQ[lim - 1]
    ]
```

`sumConvergenceErmakoff[1/(n Log[n] Log[n Log[n]]), n]`

> ```
> True
> ```